Why socket.io recommends not to listen to events inside Child components?
I have a React app with many pages. Inside one of the pages, I need real-time communication with the server. So, we started using socket.io. But, the doc said as follow
Listeners in a child component
We strongly advise against registering event listeners in your child components, because it ties the state of the UI with the time of reception of the events: if the component is not mounted, then some messages might be missed.
When the event is emmited, we are updating the data of certain endpoints which are only being used in that one specific page/component. If I were to register events at the root level, that means that event will always be triggering. So, the data will always be updated. We don't care about the data update unless user is on that specific page.
What is the good practice and what should be done?

We don't care about the data update unless user is on that specific page. When the specific page loads, do you want it to initially show no data, or the last event that happened prior to page load?

We care about that. For that, I was thinking about getting the latest data from the server as soon as component mounts. For the rest, socket.io will handle to keep that data up to date.

If you want to receive events with updates on one page only, you don't have to follow advice from socket.io documentation. But you will need to fetch the data from api endpoint on page mount. Nothing wrong to use socket.io only on the pages you need to receive updates, and not on every page.
So:

When page is mounted, fetch current state from your endpoint,
subscribe to events you need to receive updates in real time.

Here is an example how you could achieve it:

const client = io(SOCKET_IO_URL, {});

function YourPage() {
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);
   
   // fetch initial state
   useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
          const res = await fetch('https://api-url.com/endpint');
          const data = await res.json();
          setData(data);
      };
      fetchData();
   }, []);

   // subscribe for updates
   useEffect(() => {
      function onNewItem(value) {
         // note, using callback version of setData frees us from the necessity to provide data as a dependency to useEffect
         setData(data => [...data, value]);
      } 
      client.on('newItem', onNewItem);
      // don't forget to unsubscribe;
      return () => {
         client.off('newItem', onNewItem);
      }
   }, []);
   return (
     <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}}</div>
   );
}

